# Is it correct to require a package inside his own Task? [Gulp]

Tags: javascript, gulp, require

I've recently started working with `Gulp`, and I found many different `Gulpfile.js` structures.

Recently I've worked with a structure like the one below:

```
/* All requires are in the top of the archive */
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    ...;

/* here comes the tasks */
```

And now I'm working with something like this:

```
gulp.src('css', function() {
   var sass = require('gulp-sass');

   ...
});
```

Is there a difference between all requires stacked together on top of `gulpfile.js` and requires inside his own task? Performance maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a performance benefit, since you will require that module only when you execute that task. The benefit will be in the start-speed, not in the speed of executing the task itself.

In other words having `require` inside your task will be faster in most cases.

Practice usually suggest readability of your gulpfile.js, rather than speed.

In this case the speed gain will be very insignificant and you will decrease the readability.

Of course there are exceptions, but you usually run gulp inside your dev-machine or CI, not in production, so the start-speed is actually something that you would put less time on and focus on your code.